# What is the -u means in CURL and how to post a request using restTemplate with -u

Tags: java, spring, authentication, curl, resttemplate

i have cURL

```
curl -i https://thisIsValidUrl \
 -X PUT \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -u YOUR-SITE-ID-HERE:YOUR-SECRET-API-KEY-HERE \
 -d '{"email":"customer@example.com","created_at":1361205308,"first_name":"Bob","plan":"basic"}'
```

i need to post a request using spring restTemplate, but i cannot find how to use the `-u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it , it is just means to use basic authentication, i should encrypt `YOUR-SITE-ID-HERE:YOUR-SECRET-API-KEY-HERE` as Base64 String and use it in `Authorization` header

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64String);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    .
    .
    .

    HttpEntity<RaisEventRequest> request = new HttpEntity<RaisEventRequest>(RaisEventRequest, headers);

    ResponseEntity<RaisEventResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate
            .exchange(eventsURL, HttpMethod.POST, request, RaisEventResponse.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
```